# Relationship between $H_*(X, A)$ and $H_*(Y \cup_f X, Y)$? $\pi_*(X, A)$ and $\pi_*(Y \cup_f X, Y)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $A$ be a subcomplex of a CW complex $X$, let $Y$ be a CW complex, and let $f: A \to Y$ be a cellular map. What is the relationship between $H_*(X, A)$ and $H_*(Y \cup_f X, Y)$? Is there a similar relationship between $\pi_*(X, A)$ and $\pi_*(Y \cup_f X, Y)$?

Apologies in advance if this question is sort of remedial...

Comment: For homology, they're isomorphic. For homotopy, they're isomorphic through a range depending on the connectivity of these spaces. For details, look for the word "excision" in any standard algebraic topology textbook, e.g. Hatcher.

Comment: Could I have a counterexample to isomorphism in the case for homotopy?

Comment: Start with the wedge of a circle and a sphere and then fill in the disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding my comment:

The natural map $H_*(X,A)\rightarrow H_*(X\cup_f Y, Y)$ is an isomorphism, this is the so-called "excision axiom".

The map $\pi_i(X,A)\rightarrow \pi_i(X\cup_f Y, Y)$ is an isomorphism through $i<n+m$, where $n,m$ are the connectivities of the maps $A\rightarrow X$, $A\rightarrow Y$, cf. Hatcher, theorem 4.23.

To see that it cannot generally hold, consider $X=D^n$, $A=\partial D^n$, $Y=pt$. The map takes the form
$$
\pi_i(D^n,\partial D^n)\rightarrow \pi_i(S^n)
$$
The left side is isomorphic to $\pi_{i-1}(\partial D^n)$, and the map coincides with the suspension homomorphism $\pi_{i-1}(S^{n-1})\rightarrow \pi_i(S^n)$. This is not an isomorphism.

This is not surprising at all, since excision is more or less the thing that axiomatically characterizes homology. In fact, the standard calculation of $H_*(S^n)$ uses basically only excision.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to be said in the case of $\pi_*$. Of course we assume all the spaces are connected and pointed. Let $Z= X \cup_f Y$. Then we have a **triad** $(Z:Y,X)$ whose homotopy groups were first studied by Blakers and Massey, see this [ncatlab](http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Blakers-Massey+theorem) reference.

There is also some more information which can be obtained using the techniques given in the EMS Tract vol 15 (2011)  partially titled [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html) (NAT) (pdf available). Thus we can consider the homotopical excision morphism $$\varepsilon_n: \pi_n(X,A) \to \pi_n(Z,Y).$$ Note that there is a morphism $\lambda: \pi_1(A) \to \pi_1(Y)$ induced by $f: A \to Y$, and the displayed groups are **modules** over these fundamental groups if $n >2$, and 
**crossed modules** if $n=2$. Suppose the pair $(X,A)$ is $(n-1)$-connected.  Then $(Z,Y)$ is $(n-1)$-connected and $$\pi_n(Z,Y) \cong \lambda_*(\pi_n(X,A)),$$ 
the "induced" module if $n>2$ and induced crossed module if $n=2$. This result is Corollary 5.4.2 of NAT if $n=2$ and Theorem 8.3.9 of NAT if $n>2$. Notice that if $n=2$ this is a nonabelian result: NAT contains a number of calculations using this result, which generalises a Theorem of J.H.C. Whitehead on free crossed modules in his paper "Combinatorial Homotopy II", a Theorem  which is sometimes stated,  but rarely proved,  in texts on algebraic topology. These results generalise the Relative Hurewicz Theorem and are Corollaries of a Higher Homotopy Seifert-van Kampen Theorem (HHSvKT).

Indeed, as stated in the ncatlab reference, the algebraic form of the Blakers-Massey Theorem, not just the connectivity part,  is also a consequence of a more general HHSvKT, see [this exposition](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/VKTEVAN2.pdf).

Some expository presentations are available on my [preprint page](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/brownpr.html).